# How to produce ScrollView with several lists (RecyclerView) inside like in YAZIO?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I need to produce a list of a week (7 entries), each entry must provide list of another entries like in YAZIO, how can I achieve that ?

[image: Screenshot]

I've tried to set 7 `RecyclerView` with height to wrap content, but then there is problem: only the first displays in its full height.
Using several ViewTypes doesn't fit as I want to use `MaterialCardView` for each day.

Eventually I want to achieve result like this, in each row may be, or not included list:

[image: Screenshot]

For now I achieved this by using `ListView` in `RecyclerView` and recalculating `ListView`'s height in `onBindViewHolder()` method. This seems not to be correct, though it somehow works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a ***nestedscrollview*** for that.

Here is an example of xml code which can display 2 diffents recyclerview in its full height.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".com.example.thomas.EasyCount.BalanceFragment">




<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">



    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">




    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycle_depenses1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>



        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycle_pay_back"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/txt_to_do"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

So you should use nestedscrollview like this :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">




<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

//ALL OF YOUR CONTENT MUST BE IN THE LINEALAYOUT => Nested scroll must only have one child

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```